# Laravel 4 to 5 transition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a large project which is coded in Laravel 4. Directory structure is somewhat changed than standard in a way that there is one folder which contains separated pieces of code (sort of like modules) where each one has its own models, controllers, repositories etc.

I am thinking about transitioning to Laravel 5, and I've read that the recommended way is making a fresh installation and copy pasting everything. However, this is an app in production and it is constantly being filled with new functionalities so I can't just take a month to copy paste everything and test it out thoroughly, but rather make a smooth transition.

I am aware that the question may be too broad, but can I make some code modifications in a way that they will still work in Laravel 4 while making the transition to Laravel 5 easier? For example...namespace this, transfer this there, make class that does this...etc?

Comment: you will have to do the manual labour but luckilly you can use most of the files as is and just need to move them over to the new folder structure..try the changes stagewise on your development server and then you can push it live..

Comment: What is your estimate on the job? Are we talking hours or days?

Comment: You could take a look at [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade). You have all the instructions on how to update step by step..

Comment: what is the current version? (4.?)

Comment: Current version is 4.2

Comment: @Norgul ., I would say at max a few days to a couple of weeks depending on the size of your project

Comment: I would go step by step approach, especially if it has a lot of custom logic in place.

Comment: Don't forget to use git. Could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I can prefer you just install a fresh Laravel 5 in your system. Then manually copy and past all the controllers, models, database and so on... 
If you don't want to spend time upgrading manually, there's a service called  [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/.) which is an automated way to upgrade Laravel applications. You can upgrade to the latest version of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to you I have migrated from `4.x -> 5.5`. It didn't go too smoothly. I would recommend transferring your 'modules' over first in a new Laravel project and start updating code from there. Those Modules are likely to be the most project-breaking components.

Things like Authentication really got me out, and rather than updating, I should have just rewritten this.

I've spent a good 2 weeks updating an Application. Can you afford to have this time as downtime? If I could do it again, I would probably pay for [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/).